# Auto add Slash / symbol in Date <input> box by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, regex

*(I find several question but no answer, so i asked question)* 

How to add auto Slash / symbol in `<input>` box when input/type Date? 

Example: when type 02 or any date, month, year number, jquery will auto add / symbol after 2 number in input box, like 02/12/2016 

please Check jsfiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/rjkdd9j6/

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="your-id" value="dd/mm/yy">
```

Is there any simple solution by jquery or JS ?

Comment: </input> is not a tag in html

Comment: @mlegg any solution please ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Something like this will work. Check the attached JSFiddle too.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('#your-id').bind('keyup','keydown', function(event) {
    var inputLength = event.target.value.length;
    if(inputLength === 2 || inputLength === 5){
      var thisVal = event.target.value;
      thisVal += '/';
      $(event.target).val(thisVal);
    }
  })
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ahmedhawas7/rjkdd9j6/3/

You can also use an input mask library like this Jquery one: https://github.com/RobinHerbots/jquery.inputmask

Comment: Nice, but when type single date like 2/12/2016 it's showing result like this 2//12/2016  any fix please?

Comment: @Aariba cool. I updated it to guard from backspace too: https://jsfiddle.net/ahmedhawas7/rjkdd9j6/3/

Comment: Great, Then please update the answer.

Comment: Why down Vote my question?

Comment: I can type `14/46/67645789766` there. I don't think that is expected.

Comment: When you spam number keys it doesn't add the slashes properly

Comment: @AhmedHawas, It's also accepting the 50/50/122244545. any other solution?

Comment: use maxlength="10" in input field

Answer (score 2):

Attach an onkeydown event handler to your `<input>` box and whenever length of  input box's value is 2 or 5 append an '/' to it.

fiddle :- https://jsfiddle.net/nuh4dy6j/
`

```
var input = document.querySelector('input');
input.addEventListener('keydown', ev => {
  var ipLength = ev.target.value.length;
  if(ipLength ===2 || ipLength ===5) {
    ev.target.value += '/';
  }
});
```

Comment: please provide jsfiddle example with jquery :)

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/nuh4dy6j/

Comment: This does not allow you to backspace past a /, and also allows as many characters as you want at the end of the string without inserting more /s.

Answer (score -1):

You can do like this, give a try

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
      $("#inputDate").keyup(function(){
            if ($(this).val().length == 2){
                    $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
            }else if ($(this).val().length == 5){
                  $(this).val($(this).val() + "/");
            }
       });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="inputDate" type="text" />
```

Comment: not properly working ....

Comment: It's working no?? click the Run Code snippet and check @Aariba